# echo %DATE% output

Tags: windows, batch-file

When i run my below batch script, I received an error

> Invalid switch - /d:"

Can someone please help me with this?

My batch file script to copy file:

```
@ECHO OFF
  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%V IN ("%DATE%") DO SET TDY=%%V
  xcopy /y "\\page1\page\*.*" "D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop\day\*.*" /d:%TDY%
  SET TDY=
@pause
```

Comment: The value `%TDY%` is not correct, print it out.  What is in `%DATE%`?

Comment: I use this command to copy today's file to another folder

Comment: @AlexK. asks for `echo %DATE%` output. Please [edit] your question and add it. Read `xcopy /?`.

Answer (score 1):

Try for example in explorer to rename a folder with date formatted like this dd/mm/yyyy

You getting this error because you are trying to create/rename a file with slash "`/`" separator.

You need to parse the date with the right delims and tokens.
The delims here is `/` and tokens `1,2,3` or `1-3` (meaning `1 to 3`)

Edit: your date format show `Fri 25/09/2015` so I updated the table representation, `tokens` and `delims` in batch script.

```
    Fri   d d / m m / y y y y
     1  |  2  |  3  |    4
        | %%a | %%b |   %%c
   _____|_____|_____|________
```

here you go.

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do set tdy=%%c%%b%%a
xcopy /y "\\page1\page\*.*" "d:\users\kskkuga\desktop\day\" /d:%tdy%
exit /b 0
```

**Resource you must read:**

- `for /?`
- `xcopy /?`
- http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your reply. May i know how i can edit this if my date formatted like this mm/dd/yyy???

Comment: I tried with dd/mm/yyyy and this is the output: D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %a in ('echo Fri 25/09/2
015') do tdy=%c%b%a

D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>tdy=201509Fri 25
'tdy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>xcopy /y "\\page1\page\*.*"
 "d:\users\kskkuga\desktop\day\*.*" /d:
Invalid switch - /d:

D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: it still did not copy today's file... output was D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %a in ('echo 09/25
/2015') do set tdy=%c%b%a

D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>set tdy=201525

D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>xcopy /y "\\page1\page\*.*" "d:\users\kskkuga\desktop\day\*.*" /d:201525
Invalid parameter - /d:201525

D:\Users\kskkuga\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @KSR why are you changing your regional DATE format? It was  `('echo Fri 25/09/2 015')` and now `('echo 09/25 /2015')` ?

Comment: The date is set 9/25/2015. Is there any other way i can set the date in this format mm/dd/yyy?

Comment: @KSR yes change to this `tdy=%%a%%b%%c`